# increase or decrease binding value in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I have this control in my XAML and I simply want to increase or decrease the quantity when i press the button, any smart idea on how to access my observable collection directly from the click_event and edit the value? 
I tried to reach the itemsource of the parent but I have no clue on how to make it work...

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Content="-"
                                                        Click="Button_Click" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                           Text="{x:Bind quantity}" />
                                                <Button Grid.Column="2"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Content="+" />
                                            </Grid>
```

[image]

and here you can see the structure of the source:

```
 menu.Add(new MainCategories() { CategoryName = "tittle2", Visible = false });
            menu[1].SubMenuItems.Add(new Dishes() { dishName = "dishab", dishPrice = 13, quantity = 0 });
```

Comment: I would create my UserControl - it's view and viewmodel, then ObeservableCollection would contain number of viewmodel items - and theese buttons actions would be implemented within any control that list contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way of doing it without changing too much would be:

The sender of the button click event should be the Button type, which you can cast.

The DataContext Property of this button(the sender) should be able to cast to whatever type you are binding to to get your Quantity in the textblock. which you can then increment.

**However I would recommend that you look into MVVM and Commanding.**

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked as expected, this is for sure a quick way to do this but as you say its dirty... Is it dirty because the code is harder to understand or is it bad for performance too?